# Why does the gazebo gui not run correctly?

Tags: ubuntu, user-interface, ros

I installed Gazebo version 11.14.0 and ROS Noetic in Ubuntu 20.04 via WSL2. When i want to run gazebo with the command "rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo", the GUI opens but shows only blurred windows.(see attached image)
Why can't i run the simulation environment? Any suggestions?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JHmC.png)

Thanks in advance.